# Wordpress query with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I need a bit help from you. I have a custom search engine to search products from a post type taxonomy :

```
if( isset($_POST['search_products'] ) {
    /// codes ....
    $_SESSION['ids'] = $my_ids;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'showposts' => -1,
        'post__in' => $_SESSION['ids']
    )
    $posts = new Wp_Query($args);
}
```

This query outputs about 60 products with pagination (10 products per page), but when user visits the page without using the search engine, all products should be displayed. Instead, the `$_SESSION` remains and display only the previous results.

I just want the pagination working when I do search, and all products displayed when I access the page without using the search engine.

Does any Wordpress expert have an idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this link: http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( isset($_POST['search_products'] ) {
    /// codes ....
    $_SESSION['ids'] = $my_ids;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'showposts' => -1,
        'post__in' => $_SESSION['ids']
    )
    $posts = new Wp_Query($args);
}
else {

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'showposts' => -1,
    )
    $posts = new Wp_Query($args);
}
```

simply put an else block

Comment: Or maybe cleaner:
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'showposts' => -1,
)
if ( isset( $_POST['search_products'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['ids'] = $my_ids;
    $args['post__in'] = $_SESSION['ids'];
}
$posts = new Wp_Query( $args );

Comment: Hello thanks, you're in right but i have to send form as $_GET too, it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

CODE ,

```
global $post;
$id   = intval($_GET['cat']);
$paged     = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$products  = new WP_Query( array( 
                                'post_type'      => 'products', 
                                'order'          => 'ASC',
                                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                                'paged'          => $paged
                         ) );
endwhile;
```

HTML ,

```
<ul class="pagination pull-right">
 <li><?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Next Page', $products->max_num_pages ); ?></li>
 <li><?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Previous Page' ); ?></li>
</ul>
```